# Pandas remove sqare braces and single quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows and i want to remove square braces and single quote sign (') and commas.

```
id  currentTitle1
1   ['@@@0000070642@@@']
2   ['@@@0000082569@@@']
3   ['@@@0000082569@@@']
4   ['@@@0000082569@@@']
5   ['@@@0000060910@@@', '@@@0000039198@@@']
6   ['@@@0000060910@@@']
7   ['@@@0000129849@@@']
8   ['@@@0000082569@@@']
9   ['@@@0000082569@@@', '@@@0000060905@@@', '@@@0000086889@@@']
10  ['@@@0000082569@@@']
```

I want output as follows

```
id  currentTitle1
1   @@@0000070642@@@
2   @@@0000082569@@@
3   @@@0000082569@@@
4   @@@0000082569@@@
5   @@@0000060910@@@ @@@0000039198@@@
6   @@@0000060910@@@
7   @@@0000129849@@@
8   @@@0000082569@@@
9   @@@0000082569@@@ @@@0000060905@@@ @@@0000086889@@@
10  @@@0000082569@@@
```

I am getting the data from a regex cleaning operation as `df['currentTitle']=df['currentTitle'].str.findall(r'@{3}\d+@‌​{3}')`

Edit: Posting unclean data. Please remember there are blank rows too which haven't been included

```
id  currentTitle    currentTitle_unclean
1   @@@0000070642@@@    accompanying functions of @@@0000070642@@@ and business risk assessment - director
2   @@@0000082569@@@    account @@@0000082569@@@ - sales agent /representative at pronovias fashion group
3   @@@0000082569@@@    account manager/product @@@0000082569@@@ - handbags and accessories
4   @@@0000082569@@@    account @@@0000082569@@@ for entrepreneurs and small size companies
5   @@@0000060910@@@ @@@0000039198@@@   academic @@@0000060910@@@ , administrative, and @@@0000039198@@@ liaison coordinator
6   @@@0000060910@@@    account executive at bluefin insurance @@@0000060910@@@ limited
7   @@@0000129849@@@    account executive for interior @@@0000129849@@@ magazine inex
8   @@@0000082569@@@    account @@@0000082569@@@ high potential secondment programme
9   @@@0000082569@@@ @@@0000060905@@@ @@@0000086889@@@  account @@@0000082569@@@ @@@0000060905@@@ -energy and commodities @@@0000086889@@@ candidate
10  @@@0000082569@@@    account @@@0000082569@@@ paints, coatings, adhesives - ser, slo, cro
```

Comment: If lists: `df['currentTitle1'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))`, or `[' '.join(x) for x in df['currentTitle1']]`...

Comment: Are they lists or strings?

Comment: I got the values fro a regex, which i assume it to be a list. not sure though. when i check dtype, its appearing as 'object' df['currentTitle']=df['currentTitle'].str.findall(r'@{3}\d+@{3}')

Comment: That looks like something you should include in the question, along with the original data from before the regexp operation. Perhaps no removal of punctuation is even necessary in the end.

Comment: @IljaEverilä added the details.

Comment: Could you add a sample of unclean data as well? I think you might be confusing the representation of lists of strings contained in a DataFrame and strings.

Comment: I have added this now!!

Comment: In the end I think @not_a_robot got it from the start. `findall` produces a Series of lists of strings in your case, so if you want them as strings, map a join over them. Was just thinking that perhaps you have some steps after that convert them to string representations of lists of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `join`:

```
df['currentTitle1'] = df['currentTitle1'].apply(' '.join)    
print (df)
   id      currentTitle                               currentTitle_unclean  \
0   1  @@@0000070642@@@  accompanying functions of @@@0000070642@@@ and...   
1   2  @@@0000082569@@@  account @@@0000082569@@@ - sales agent /repres...   
2   3  @@@0000082569@@@  account manager/product @@@0000082569@@@ - han...   
3   4  @@@0000082569@@@  account @@@0000082569@@@ for entrepreneurs and...   
4   5  @@@0000060910@@@  @@@0000039198@@@   academic @@@0000060910@@@ ,...   
5   6  @@@0000060910@@@  account executive at bluefin insurance @@@0000...   
6   7  @@@0000129849@@@  account executive for interior @@@0000129849@@...   
7   8  @@@0000082569@@@  account @@@0000082569@@@ high potential second...   
8   9  @@@0000082569@@@  @@@0000060905@@@ @@@0000086889@@@  account @@@...   
9  10  @@@0000082569@@@  account @@@0000082569@@@ paints, coatings, adh...   

                                       currentTitle1  
0                                   @@@0000070642@@@  
1                                   @@@0000082569@@@  
2                                   @@@0000082569@@@  
3                                   @@@0000082569@@@  
4  @@@0000039198@@@ @@@0000060910@@@ @@@000003919...  
5                                   @@@0000060910@@@  
6                                   @@@0000129849@@@  
7                                   @@@0000082569@@@  
8  @@@0000060905@@@ @@@0000086889@@@ @@@000008256...  
9                                   @@@0000082569@@@
```

Or as mentioned [not_a_robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263331/pandas-remove-sqare-braces-and-single-quotes/44263739#comment75534719_44263331):

```
df['currentTitle1'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

If error:

> TypeError: can only join an iterable

then is possible add condition if not list let original value:

```
df['currentTitle1'] = df['currentTitle1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if type(x) == list 
                                                                      else x)
```

Or create empty string:

```
df['currentTitle1'] = df['currentTitle1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if type(x) == list 
                                                                      else '')
```

Comment: In both the examples, I am getting error TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: It means there are some `None` or `NaN` values, so need `df['currentTitle1'] = df['currentTitle1'].combine_first(pd.Series([[]], index=df.index)).apply(' '.join)`

Comment: still getting the same error with new code and yes there are blanks too

Comment: Ok, your code worked. It was a silly NaN value that was causing the error which i found after debugging for almost 3 hours. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

This works on my machine, created `dataframe` as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = ['accompanying functions of @@@0000070642@@@ and business risk assessment - director',
'account @@@0000082569@@@ - sales agent /representative at pronovias fashion group',
'account manager/product @@@0000082569@@@ - handbags and accessories',
'account @@@0000082569@@@ for entrepreneurs and small size companies',
'academic @@@0000060910@@@ , administrative, and @@@0000039198@@@ liaison coordinator',
'account executive at bluefin insurance @@@0000060910@@@ limited',
'account executive for interior @@@0000129849@@@ magazine inex',
'account @@@0000082569@@@ high potential secondment programme',
'account @@@0000082569@@@ @@@0000060905@@@ -energy and commodities @@@0000086889@@@ candidate',
'account @@@0000082569@@@ paints, coatings, adhesives - ser, slo, cro']

df = pd.DataFrame({'currentTitle_unclean': data})
df['currentTitle'] = df['currentTitle_unclean'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'@{3}\d+@{3}', x)))
```